# Cannot specify target table 's' for update in FROM clause in MySQL BEFORE INSERT trigger using SELECT for the same table

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, sql-update

How to resolve the error in trigger when trying to get paid_on of the latest membership payment (if exists) and set it as paid_till of the inserted record?

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb_myisam`.`shop_payment_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `shop_payment` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_paid_till DATE;

    **SELECT MAX(paid_till) INTO last_paid_till FROM shop_payment
    WHERE shop_id = NEW.shop_id
    AND paid_till > NEW.paid_on;**
    
    SET NEW.paid_on = IFNULL(last_paid_till, CURRENT_DATE);

    CASE NEW.tariff_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 
    SET NEW.paid_till = DATE_ADD(NEW.paid_on, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
    SET NEW.transaction_fee = 0.2;
    WHEN 2 THEN
    SET NEW.paid_till = DATE_ADD(NEW.paid_on, INTERVAL 90 DAY);
    SET NEW.transaction_fee = 0.5;
    WHEN 3 THEN
    SET NEW.paid_till = DATE_ADD(NEW.paid_on, INTERVAL 180 DAY);
    SET NEW.transaction_fee = 2;
    WHEN 4 THEN
    SET NEW.paid_till = DATE_ADD(NEW.paid_on, INTERVAL 365 DAY);
    SET NEW.transaction_fee = 5;
    END CASE;
END
```

I have tried to use SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(paid_till) ...) but it didn't work, also was attempt to use temporary table in trigger.

```
SET NEW.paid_on = IFNULL(
    (SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT MAX(paid_till)
       FROM shop_payment
       WHERE shop_id = NEW.shop_id
       AND paid_till > NEW.paid_on)
    as temp),
    CURRENT_DATE);
```

Structure of `shop_payment` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_payment` (
  `paypal_payment_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tariff_id` int NOT NULL,
  `details` text COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transaction_fee` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `paid_on` date NOT NULL DEFAULT (curdate()),
  `paid_till` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`paypal_payment_id`,`shop_id`),
  KEY `fk_shop_payment_shop_tariff1_idx` (`tariff_id`),
  KEY `fk_shop_payment_shop1_idx` (`shop_id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `paid_on_idx` (`paid_on`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `shop_paid_till_paid_on` (`shop_id`,`paid_till`,`paid_on`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `paid_till_shop_paid_on` (`paid_till`,`shop_id`,`paid_on`),
  KEY `shop_payment_tariff_paid_idx` (`tariff_id`,`paid_on`),
  KEY `shop_paid` (`shop_id`,`paid_on`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE shop_payment`.

Comment: Thank you, I have added this information

Comment: Ok, I have tested this on MySQL 8.2.0 and I get no error. Can you verify what does `SELECT VERSION();` return in your instance?

Comment: Yes, the version is '8.0.33'

Comment: Now I tested on 8.0.35 (the version available as a Docker image), and I still get no error. I had to make up sample data. Sorry, I cannot reproduce any problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I understand, good luck you too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into issue. Due to my mistake, the data was being inserted into a copy of the database with another engine, and the error was not displayed correctly. I have double-checked a hundred times before posting the question here. And in the end, it turned out awkward. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. We've all made that mistake!